# python list to subprocess in for loop

Tags: python

In python if I have interfaces = netifaces.interfaces() which is a list returning: 
['lo','eth0','eth1']

how to I loop over that list passing lo and eth0, eth1 into several subprocess calls to ethtool?

```
subprocess.call(['ethtool %'] interfaces) --- lo
subprocess.call(['ethtool %'] interfaces) --- eth0
subprocess.call(['ethtool %'] interfaces) --- eth1
```

I want to run ethtool for the number of items in my interfaces list but for each pass I want to substitute the next item in the interfaces list and pass that to the subprocess.call.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just put this in a for loop, as your question title states?

Comment: yes. I want to put it in a for loop but how to I pass in each item of the interfaces list on each pass?    

   for interface in interfaces:
   subprocess.call(['ethtool %'] ????)

Comment: I see. I've added an answer. The list you are passing to `call` is a list of arguments. So just provide interface as the second item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you just want to do a normal for loop...

```
interfaces = netifaces.interfaces()
for interface in interfaces:
    subprocess.call(["ethtool", interface])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for interface in interfaces:
    print("[+] Fetching LLDP info for ", interface)
    subprocess.call(['lldptool', '-t', '-n', '-i', interface])
    print("[+] Printing ethtool info for ", interface)
    subprocess.call(['ethtool', interface])
```

I turns out I was passing in the interface outside of the subprocess call and once I put it inside the [] it worked as expected. I love this site! Thank you shadow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The convention here is to upvote (click the up arrow) and/or accept (click the check mark so it turns green) the answer(s) which helped you.